# I need help getting values out of a snapshot from firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My Data in Firebase looks like this:

[image: schema]

I am retrieving the data with

```
 var ref: DatabaseReference
    ref = Database.database().reference()

    ref.child("peopleReminders").child("-LBO0TMbOM0cwd5TMMiP").observe(.value) { snapshot in
         for  value in snapshot.children {
            print(value)

        }

    }
```

This prints the following:

```
Snap (0) r04
Snap (1) r02
Snap (2) r01
```

This should be an array. What I need to do is get the values `R04`, `R02`, and `R01` out of it.

Comment: What does `snapshot.value` print? Also you should use `observeSingle` instead of `observe` if you want to get data just once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `loop` or `enumeration` to parse it into an array as `Firebase` supports both `Array` and `Dictionary`. You can directly cast the result into an array. Below piece of code will work:

```
ref.child("peopleReminders").child("-LBO0TMbOM0cwd5TMMiP").observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value) { (snapshot) in
     if snapshot.exists() {
         let result: [String] = snapshot.value as? [String] ?? []
         print(result)
     }
}
```

> **Note:** Always check `snapshot` existence it will be false if data doesn't exist for the requested reference. Use `observeSingleEvent` when you need to fetch the data for once if you use `observe` the call back will be call many times whenever there is a change in requested node so that **delete**, **insert**, **update** etc.

Comment: @ScottFarestrand Could you please accept any answer if your problem has been resolved?

Answer (score 1):

I replaced for  value in snapshot.children  with the following code.

```
let enumerator = snapshot.children
while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot {
    print(rest.value!)
}
```

The new output is now:
R04
R02
R01